# Acess a uitextfield that has not tag

Tags: uitableview, tags, subview

I have a tableview with multiple dynamic tableview cells, and inside each tableviewcell i have multiple textfields. Each cell has a different tag, but the texfields don´t! and i need to retrieve the information the user will insert later on them. I´m using the interface builder.

Is it possible to access a texfield that isn´t tagged?.

Can i manage this using the "user defined Runtime Attributes"?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake when starting with iOS.

You should not be referring directly to the textfield in order to retrieve the information stored in it, **especially** in a table view.  In a table view, when a cell scrolls off the screen, the cell will very likely get reused and the information that was stored there is gone forever.

Instead, store the text when the user finishes editing the textfield by setting your view controller as the textfield delegate and then implementing the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Store the textField.text value somewhere for later use.
}
```

Comment: So i have to create a "lot of" extFieldDidEndEditing events (because i have many texfields in each cell) and this way i will be able to access them?. I mean, i should connect that event in the IB for each textfield and then treat them in the extFieldDidEndEditing method? thanks for your help

Comment: No, there is only one `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method, and all of the textField's call that same one.  You need some way to tell them apart.  Usually in tableview's you use a combination of tag's (I would #define constants for them like MYTABLEVIEWROW_NAME_TAG) and the row number.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. So i have no other choice but to use tag on each textfield that is inside each uitableviewcell?. My problem is that my cells have at least 6 texfield´s inside them, and they are dynamic..so every time the user pushes the green plus button, new tag´s are created? i don´t know this...i´m stuck!.

Comment: If you want to be able to tell the difference between them, then yes.  You need to tag each one.  Each row can have the same tag for the same textfield though.  (i.e. if each row has a "Name" textfield then they should all have the same tag number so that in your code, you can just use `if (textField.tag == NAME_TAG) { // You know this is a name }`

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no problem having for example: row (tag 1) with 6 texfields (tag 2,3,4,5,6,7) and then when the user pushes a new row, it will be row(tag 2) with texfields (tag 2,3,4,5,6,7). The texfields ALWAYS remain with the same tag...sorry for asking so many questions, but you are really helping me. thanks

Comment: Correct.  Then you just take the "name" (tag 2) for row 1, then tag 2 in row 2 is the name for your second record, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can go over each cell subviews and check if it a UITextField, something like:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        // do something with the text field...
    }
}
```

Having said that, this is probably not the best approach... U will do better given each textField a tag or subclassing the cell with a custom cell that has textFields as properties.

Comment: but how can i distinguish each texfield inside each cell if i didn´t tag them?